# How can I get the total value to be displayed in the template?

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a subtotal for each group of items in an array. I am able to display the list and to compute the running total in the component, however, the value is not displayed.

I used the trackBy to initiate the computation (maybe there's a better way). I try using ngDoCheck and ngAfterContentChecked to update the view. The value to be displayed is computed but I'm not able to have it reflected in the template.

Here's a sample of the code.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let invoice of sortedList">
    <span>{{invoice.key}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of invoice.value; trackBy: sumAmounts;">
            <span class="row">{{item.DATE | date: "d/M/y"}}</span>
            <span class="row">{{item.INVOICE}}</span>
            <span class="row">{{item.AMOUNT | currency: 'USD':'symbol-narrow'}}</span>
            <span class="row">{{item.TAX}}</span>
            <span class="row">{{item.DU_DATE | date: "d/M/y"}}</span>
            <span class="row">;{{item.DAYS}}</span>
       </li>
       <div class="line"</div>
       <div>
          <span>Totals:</span>
          <span>{{runningTot | currency: 'USD':'symbol-narrow'}}</span>
       </div>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

`
In the component

```
sumAmounts(index, rec) {
    if (rec.CODE != this.cusId) {
        this.runningTot = rec.AMOUNT;
        this.cusId = rec.CODE;
        console.log('initialized value: ', this.runningTot);
        this.summ = true;  // not relevant
        this.counter++;   // used to trigger ngDoCheck
    }
    else {
        this.runningTot = this.runningTot + rec.AMOUNT;
        console.log('Addition ', this.runningTot);
    }
}
```

I want the runningTot to be displayed in the template whenever a new customer id is detected. The value in the template remains at 0, even though the the variable 'runningTot' has a value.

DoCheck function is shown below:

```
  ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.counter != this.prv_Counter) {
            this.prv_counter = this.counter;
        }
            console.log('do check');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `trackBy` and just code something like this :

```
// component.ts
get runningTot() {
  // loop through your array and return the sum
}
```

Btw, `this.counter++;   // used to trigger ngDoCheck` looks like a big red flag to me, since you rely on a strange side effect to re-render your view

Comment: I suggest calculating the totals in a method in the component when the list is updated, and using the template only for displaying the data. Life is a lot simpler if you maintain that separation.

Comment: I thought of that however how do I transform a list like:  list2 = [{id: "01", value: [{name: "Peter Parker", amount: 52.4}, {name: "Peter Parker", amount: 62.5}]}, {id: "02", value: [{name: "Andrew White", amount: 32.4}]}]; to one which has both "id" and "total" (of childen) as parent enement?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pipe like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'totalCount'
})
export class TotalCountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], args?: any): any {
    return value.map(v => v.AMOUNT).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
  }
}
```

please register the pipe in your module like:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        ...
        TotalCountPipe 
    ],
...
})
```

and in your template you could use:

```
...
<div>
          <span>Totals:</span>
          <span>{{invoice.value| totalCount | currency: 'USD':'symbol-narrow'}}</span>
       </div>
...
```

Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xrkrm

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know if it works.